# Rails simple_forms collections radio button broken down

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, collections, label, simple-form

I am attempting to make a voting system for some video. On the vote page I want a radio button for each finalist and next to it an image pulled form youtube the file name and the finalist name. I have a domain for submission and user and made a domain for the voting that is associate to both with the fields submission_id and user_id with submission has_many votes and users has_one vote. Using simple form I create the following:

```
= simple_form_for @vote do |f|
  = f.input :submission_id, :as => :radio, :collection => @finalists, :label_method => :file_name, :value_method => :id, :label => false
  = f.submit "Submit Vote 2"
```

This does work and it puts up a radio button for each and allows the user to select on of the submissions to vote for. However,  wanted to put next to the radio button a thumbnail and some text to make it clear what they are voting for. I tried just making a field of HTMl text that of the all the information I wanted: 
`<img src="youtube/thumbnail" /> <div> Text for label</div>`
However, it just prints out the HTML mark up. tried `raw(:file_name)` but that errored out with bad syntax.

At this point I though I might just need to break down the colleciton and make the loop my self. I tryed the following:

```
= simple_form_for @vote do |f|
  - @finalists.each do |finalist|
    = f.input :submission_id, :as => :radio, :value => finalist.id, :input_html => {:name => 'vote[submisison_id]', :id => "vote_submission_id_#{finalist.id}", :value => finalist.id}
  = f.submit "Submit Vote"
```

This results in 5 different radio button collections with their values being yes/no. I of course want one set of radio buttons where one of the submissions gets selected.

I have looked up a few different page on radio_button_tag and collections and I am having a lot of troubles trying to figure out how to tell rails that I want all the radio button to be part of the same set.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.